# Query to extended user model returning error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I am receiving an error when making the following query:

```
Election.objects.all().exclude(candidate__UserID=request.user).filter(Gender=request.user.Profile.Gender).filter(CandidateReg=True)
```

To this model:

```
class Election(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    CandidateReg = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    VotingOpen = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    GENDERS = (("M","Male"), ("F","Female"))
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDERS, default="M")
    Seats = models.IntegerField(default=7)
    FlipGrid = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True)
    Complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

The problem is described in this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/elections/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
        response = get_response(request)
      File "/home/elections/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 187, in _get_response
        response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
      File "/home/elections/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 185, in _get_response
        response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
      File "/home/elections/elections-real/elections/views.py", line 139, in add_candidate
        elections = Election.objects.all().exclude(candidate__UserID=request.user).filter(Gender=request.user.Profile.Gender).filter(CandidateReg=True)
      File "/home/elections/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 239, in inner
        return func(self._wrapped, *args)
    AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'Profile'
```

It appears to show the issue is with the reference to `Gender`data in the current user's profile - an extension of the user model. This is shown here:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    UserID = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    GENDERS = (("M","Male"), ("F","Female"))
    Gender = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=GENDERS)
    UserTypeID = models.ForeignKey(UserType, on_delete=models.PROTECT, blank=True, null=True)
    EmailConfirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(UserID=instance)

@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_user_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

How do I correctly reference the `Gender` attribute of the logged-in user's profile if not the way outlined above?

Comment: What is Election and how does it relate to Profile?

Comment: @DanielRoseman `Election` is a model which also has a field called `Gender`. I want to make sure that the election models returned have the same gender value as the user's profile. I have edited the question to explain this better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reverse accessor of a one-to-one field is always the *lower-cased* name of the model: so it would be `request.user.profile...`.

This would be less surprising to you if you followed standard PEP-8 compliant style and named all your fields with lower case - `gender`, `voting_open`, `email_confirmed` etc. Also note it is not best practice to give relationship fields names ending with `ID` as they give access to the whole related object, not just the ID, so your `UserID` should be called just `user`.

Finally, on gender, please read [Falsehoods Programmers believe about Gender](https://medium.com/gender-2-0/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-gender-f9a3512b4c9c) and consider whether you really need to ask this information.

Comment: Thank you very much for this advice. The solution has worked and I will definitely use clearer convention as you have stated in future.